# MySQL ignores index issue

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

during recent MySQL (v5.5) monitoring of our website we've found it generates quite often such a heavy query:

```
SELECT b.PRODUCT_ID, b1.PRODUCT_ID, 1 FROM b_sale_basket b, b_sale_basket b1 
WHERE b.ORDER_ID = b1.ORDER_ID AND b.ORDER_ID = 15500 AND b.ID <> b1.ID AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b_sale_product2product d 
     WHERE d.PRODUCT_ID = b.PRODUCT_ID AND d.PARENT_PRODUCT_ID = b1.PRODUCT_ID);
```

It runs more than 60 seconds. And returns 12K rows.

**b_sale_product2product** has 51 million records, **b_sale_basket** has 640K records.

All used fields have respected indexes. Just can't find a reason why is it so painfully long.

Please help.

Table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE `b_sale_product2product` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PRODUCT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PARENT_PRODUCT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CNT` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `IXS_PRODUCT2PRODUCT_PRODUCT_ID` (`PRODUCT_ID`),
  KEY `IXS_PRODUCT2PRODUCT_PARENT_AND_PRODUCT_ID` (`PRODUCT_ID`,`PARENT_PRODUCT_ID`),
  KEY `IXS_PRODUCT2PRODUCT_PARENT_PRODUCT_ID` (`PARENT_PRODUCT_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=52036712 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `b_sale_basket` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FUSER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ORDER_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRODUCT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PRODUCT_PRICE_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRICE` decimal(18,2) NOT NULL,
  `CURRENCY` char(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `DATE_INSERT` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DATE_UPDATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `WEIGHT` double(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   /* ... skipped ... */
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `IXS_BASKET_LID` (`LID`),
  KEY `IXS_BASKET_USER_ID` (`FUSER_ID`),
  KEY `IXS_BASKET_ORDER_ID` (`ORDER_ID`),
  KEY `IXS_BASKET_PRODUCT_ID` (`PRODUCT_ID`),
  KEY `IXS_BASKET_PRODUCT_PRICE_ID` (`PRODUCT_PRICE_ID`),
  KEY `IXS_SBAS_XML_ID` (`PRODUCT_XML_ID`,`CATALOG_XML_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=962527 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

EXPLAIN result:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys                                                                                                  | key                            | key_len | ref                     | rows | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | b     | ref  | IXS_BASKET_ORDER_ID                                                                                            | IXS_BASKET_ORDER_ID            | 5       | const                   |  179 | Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | b1    | ref  | IXS_BASKET_ORDER_ID                                                                                            | IXS_BASKET_ORDER_ID            | 5       | const                   |  179 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | d     | ref  | IXS_PRODUCT2PRODUCT_PRODUCT_ID,IXS_PRODUCT2PRODUCT_PARENT_AND_PRODUCT_ID,IXS_PRODUCT2PRODUCT_PARENT_PRODUCT_ID | IXS_PRODUCT2PRODUCT_PRODUCT_ID | 4       | b.PRODUCT_ID |    1 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: Can you use an uncorrelated subquery instead. (DECIMAL(18,2) - I guess I won't be buying too much from you!)

Comment: This index is redundant:  `KEY \`IXS_PRODUCT2PRODUCT_PRODUCT_ID\` (\`PRODUCT_ID\`)`

Comment: And WHERE's the EXPLAIN?

Comment: Thank you for your remarks. Attached an EXPLAIN. I think I'll have to take time to rewrite it in uncorrelated form. At the moment don't have an idea how to do it correctly.

Comment: Are those 'rows' figures correct!?!

Comment: Are you O.K. with b.PRODUCT_ID being the PARENT PRODUCT of b1.PRODUCT_ID?

Comment: Dudu Markovitz, Not sure why it was done such way. It's a legacy code, I assume there's problem in the code. Just figuring out how to change it so it won't be broken.

Comment: Strawberry, I assume yes, b_sale_basket is a large table. There can be many pairs of orders in clients basket.

Comment: @Strawberry - Ah, the weight of the earth in kilograms needs more than `(18,2)`.  (But not many more digits!)

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding -

```
Force index   (IXS_PRODUCT2PRODUCT_PARENT_AND_PRODUCT_ID)
```

---

```
SELECT b.PRODUCT_ID, b1.PRODUCT_ID, 1 FROM b_sale_basket b, b_sale_basket b1 
WHERE b.ORDER_ID = b1.ORDER_ID AND b.ORDER_ID = 15500 AND b.ID <> b1.ID AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
             FROM b_sale_product2product d 
                      Force index (IXS_PRODUCT2PRODUCT_PARENT_AND_PRODUCT_ID)
             WHERE d.PRODUCT_ID = b.PRODUCT_ID AND d.PARENT_PRODUCT_ID = b1.PRODUCT_ID )
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Seems this fixed the problem, execution times on tests dropped by 99%. Unfortunately there's no simple way to modify it in the code, because it is generated by the website engine. But at least now we know the cause.

Answer (score 0):

`b_sale_product2product` looks very much like a many:many mapping table, plus a `cnt`.  If that is correct, then get rid of `ID`, it only slows things down.  And fails to catch the need for the pair `product_id, parent_product_id` to be unique.  See my [*many:many tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) .  Alas, this won't actually help your current query; but it should help some others.

Or is `b_sale_product2product` a hierarchy, as "parent" implies?  If so, is there only one "parent" for each "product"?  If this is the case, the query *should* be simplifiable.

Your query start as a cross join between two tables of about 179 rows each.  This is followed by 32,041 lookups in the p2p table.  But there are really only 179 interesting rows in that table.

That is, if you start with the 179 rows (product, plus single parent), then there are only 179 things to check, not 179*179.  No cross-join.  Something like this order

```
FROM b_sale_basket
JOIN b_sale_product2product ON ...
JOIN b_sale_basket ON ...
```

(My brain had enough trouble trying to figure out what your query was trying to do; there is not enough brain power left to write out this query for you.)